Can I change encoding in R package foreign?
I am reading data like this:
Tr2309w <- read.spss('data_duvery/TR2023_09_TABS.SAV', to.data.frame = TRUE, use.value.labels = TRUE) # read in data


using package foreign. It reads correctly the content but the language is Czech typically encoded as windows-1250 which does not work here.
I can also read the data like this
Tr2305w <- read_sav('data_duvery/TR2023_5_TABS.SAV', encoding = "windows-1250" )

using haven package. Then it has the correct Czech characters encoding but the content is wrong, because it skips some of the questions.
